# How to check for the RSI going down after a top?

Tags: pine-script

I am not too experienced with pine script. I basically want my script to check for the RSI going down after double topping if possible. The method that comes to my mind is checking if the RSI has reached a certain point within the past x bars but that has some obvious constraints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't give us code you've tried to achieve your purpose, your objective is loosely defined and from what I understand of it, it may prove to be somewhat ambitious for a beginning Pine programmer. To get answers here it will be helpful if you can supply us with your attempts to code this, and more details on the conditions you are trying to identify. In case you want to consider hiring someone to code this for you, PineCoders maintain a list of Trusted Pine Programmers for Hire you can access from here:
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/SSP/FcnxLZJ7-Trusted-Pine-Programmers-For-Hire/

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF Thanks for the response. I've actually decided to work on something else for the moment, although it would be nice to know how to do this. The reason I asked because I didn't quite know where to start. I'll let you know if I'm coming back to this.